I have this subtractor circuit how to make the output non inverting?
I have the following circuit which inverts the input signal after subtracting V1 - V2. How can I  make this non inverting? I already have changed the values of V1 and V2 and it makes the output non inverting but the subtraction is not applied correctly and the result is something like 1.7. This is the output 
and this is my circuit


You're missing a resistor. If you want the gain of the noninverting path to match the gain of the inverting path, you need an additional 10k resistor from pin 3 to ground.

Your circuit calculates V2-V1. If you want to calculate V1-V2, swap the voltage supplies so that V2 goes to inverting terminal and V1 goes to non-inverting terminal.
And remove the 10x inverting gain if yoy want to end up having V1-V2.

I want to invert the output signal of V1 - V2 so I'm calculating V2 - V1. As a result the signal in inverted but it's value is not correct as it's shown in the output signals

@neitu Your inverting input has gain of 10. If you don't want that then change the gain to what you want.

no I meant the red signal value which is vin. It should be 1 but it's value is near 2

The negative feedback insures that the voltage on the inverting input of the opamp (your vin) will track the voltage on the noninverting input (your V2), so it is actually correct.  However, you're driving the opamp into clipping, which is introducing other errors.

@neitu Yes, the circuit has inverting gain of 10. With 1V amplitude in, the output amplitude would need to be 10V. But you have supply voltage of only 10V and in general op-amp outputs never reach the supply voltage. So you need higher supply if you want a gain of 10. But if you just wanted to do a subtraction between voltages so it is unclear why you want a gain of 10 as then it won't calculate the difference of the two voltages.
